# how to download ERRATA by yum without to install it

Tags: redhat, yum

by this example we can install the errata

```
yum update --advisory=RHBA-2016:0694
```

but is it possible just to download the errata to local folder?

we just want to download the rpm's , without to install them

as all know we can do it also from redhat site , but I want to use yum for download errata - is it possible

please advice

Answer (score 0):

From `yum --help`:

```
--downloadonly        don't update, just download
--downloaddir=DLDIR   specifies an alternate directory to store packages
```

Comment: why ( -1 ) , what is wrong with my question ?   , anywy I upvote for your answer

Comment: Your question does not show any research effort at all. You could have typed `yum --help` yourself.

Comment: yes I agree but I searched in google not by yum -help , so anyway sometimes we forget this option , but I do my best effort , so please consider again to up vote , thank you

Comment: can you please consider it ? please ?